# How to use each from array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I use this: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/select_row.html

Here is function return selcted rows:

```
function fnGetSelected( oTableLocal )
{
    var aReturn = new Array();
    var aTrs = oTableLocal.fnGetNodes();

    for ( var i=0 ; i<aTrs.length ; i++ )
    {
        if ( $(aTrs[i]).hasClass('row_selected') )
        {
            aReturn.push( aTrs[i] );
        }
    }
    return aReturn;
}
```

i do:

```
var arr = fnGetSelected(oTable);
```

this return me:

```
[tr.gradeA, tr.gradeA, tr.gradeA]
```

this is:

```
<tr class="gradeA even row_selected">
<td class=" sorting_1"><span class="my_values" test="aaa">Gecko</span></td>
<td>Camino 1.5</td>
<td>OSX.3+</td>
<td class="center">1.8</td>
<td class="center">A</td>
</tr>
<tr class="gradeA odd row_selected">
<td class=" sorting_1"><span class="my_values" test="bbb">Gecko</span></td>
<td>Netscape 7.2</td>
<td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
<td class="center">1.7</td>
<td class="center">A</td>
</tr>
<tr class="gradeA even">
<td class=" sorting_1"><span class="my_values" test="bbb">Gecko</span></td>
<td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
<td>Win 98SE+</td>
<td class="center">1.7</td>
<td class="center">A</td>
</tr>
```

I add for this own span.my_values with attribute **test**.
Now i would like get all attribute **test** for this.

I try:

```
    arr.each(function(index) {
        console.log($(this).children());
    });
```

but this return error: **arr.each is not a function**

How can  i make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's generic array looping function is [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each), not a member of `Array.prototype`, so:

```
$.each(arr, function() {
    console.log($(this).children());
});
```

> Now i would like get all attribute test for this.

If you'd like to get the `test` attribute of the `span` with class "my_values" inside the elements in `arr`, you can use `$.map`:

```
var testValues = $.map(arr, function() {
    return $(this).find('span.my_values[test]').attr('test');
});
```

...which gives you an array of the `test` values.

---

Side note 1: Since you're using jQuery, which is inherently set-based, rather than having your `fnGetSelected` function return an `Array` of matching elements, how 'bout having it return a `jQuery` object?

```
function fnGetSelected( oTableLocal )
{
    return $(oTableLocal.fnGetNodes()).filter('.row_selected');
}
```

That creates a jQuery object containing all of the returned nodes, then filters it to only the ones with the class "row_selected" (as your original did) and returns it.

Then you can use it like this:

```
var rows = fnGetSelected(oTableLocal);
rows.each(function() {
    console.log($(this).children());
});

var testValues = rows.map(function() {
    return $(this).find('span.my_values[test]').attr('test');
}).get();
```

---

Side note 2: "test" is an invalid attribute for `span` elements, although browsers allow it. Look at using [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) instead, e.g., "data-test" rather than "test".

Answer (score 2):

Have you try :

```
 $.each(arr, function(index) {
    console.log($(this).children());
});
```

or :

```
 $(arr).each(function(index) {
    console.log($(this).children());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method only applies to jQuery objects, not to arrays. [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), however, supports arrays, so you can use it instead:

```
$.each(arr, function() {
    console.log($(this).children());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

arr is an array. You have to do

```
$.each(arr,function(index,value) {
  console.log(value);
})
```

you can transform arr to a jQuery object and use arr.each() by changing your function:

```
function fnGetSelected( oTableLocal )
{
    var aReturn = $([]);
    var aTrs = oTableLocal.fnGetNodes();

    for ( var i=0 ; i<aTrs.length ; i++ )
    {
        if ( $(aTrs[i]).hasClass('row_selected') )
        {
            aReturn.pushStack( aTrs[i] );
        }
    }
    return aReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arr` as:

```
    $(arr).each(function(index) {
        console.log($(this).children());
    });
```